# Keeping MySQL table in sync with 3rd party API in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Our ticketing system's API is too slow so I maintain a synced copy in Laravel/MySQL for running reports.

Each night I wipe the local copy, make an HTTP request, and repopulate the tables with fresh data. I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to only create new records or update changes?

```php
$contact = new Contact();
$contact::truncate();

$response = Http::get('https://example.com/api/contacts');
$json = $response->json();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($json['items']); $i++) {
    $contact = new Contact();
    $contact->Firstname = $json['items'][$i]['Firstname'];
    $contact->Lastname = $json['items'][$i]['Lastname'];
    $contact->EndUserID = $json['items'][$i]['EndUserID'];
    $contact->Phone = $json['items'][$j]['Phone'];
    $contact->save();            
}
```

Comment: It really depends on your API - If the API has a webhooks you can get a `notification` that some data has changed and update your DB accordingly

Comment: Well, if you can access the ticketing system's DB directly you could (maybe) just bypass the API altogether. Or maybe there's a newer version that's faster. Or you can upgrade the machine's hardware. Or use database replication.

Comment: Upon closer inspection, I see a LastModified property in the API.  I guess I can query based on that and update only records that changed that day.  Then I can run a second query to copy new records.  What are the correct commands for this?  Sorry, I'm very new to Laravel.